# Convert Windows-1252 subtitle file to utf-8

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, vlc, codec

I am downloading Serbian/Bosnian/Croatian subtitles via VLC player on an Ubuntu machine, and have constantly to manually change characters such as æ, è, and ð into ć, č, and đ so that the player can render them properly. I wanted to make a python3 function that can do that for me, but I got lost tyring to understand string encoding and decoding.

Through `chardata.detect` I found that the encoding of `.srt` files that VLC player downloads is Windows-1252. So right now, I do something like this:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open('my_file.srt', 'r', encoding='Windows-1252')
data = f.read()
data_utf8 = data.encode('utf-8')
f.close()
```

The thing is, when I print to terminal the content of the `data` varible, I might get a fragment like this:
`obožavam vaše`.
But, when I print to terminal the content of the `data-utf8` variable, that same fragment now looks like this: 
`obo\xc5\xbeavam va\xc5\xa1e`.
This is not what I expected.

Furthermore, when I now want to save this data to a file

```
with open('my_utf8_file.srt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data_utf8)
```

I get `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the detected encoding is not the right one, it does not always work. For croatian, the recommended encoding is Eastern European, not Western. Can you try windows-1250 instead of 1252?

Comment: I tried your code with a file containing just obožavam vaše , encoded in windows-1252 or 1250 and it worked in both cases... Can you provide the subtitle file so I can try?

Comment: Can you share the link to the `srt`? Maybe you should try using the [Universal Encoding Detector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library.

Comment: `data.encode('utf-8').decode()`, then try to write.

Comment: Already tried most of those things, but it turned out that I just forgot to use the binary flag while writing to the file, as mousetail has noticed below. Thank you both in any case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
with open('my_utf8_file.srt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data_utf8)
```

Note the 'b', this marks the file as binary so you can write bytes (like printed by `.encode()`) This is also the reason it prints differently.

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
with open('my_utf8_file.srt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) to determine the correct file encoding.
Open a command line and type:

```
> chardetect Joker.BDRip.x264-AAA.cyr.srt
Joker.BDRip.x264-AAA.cyr.srt: windows-1251 with confidence 0.8720288218241439

> chardetect Joker.BDRip.x264-AAA.cyr_utf8.srt
Joker.BDRip.x264-AAA.cyr_utf8.srt: utf-8 with confidence 0.99
```

---

Install:

```
pip install chardet
```

---

I used this [Serbian subtitles](https://www.yifysubtitles.com/subtitle/joker2019720pblurayx264ytsag-serbian-160178.zip) to test.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm already using it; that's how I determined that the titles are encoded with Windows-2152 in the first place.

Comment: you mean `Windows-1252` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, made a typo there. Windows-1252. Used ```from chardet import detect, detect(data)['encoding']```

Comment: Neat, I didn't know I could do it from the command line, thanks! In either case I already got the correct encoding, which seems to be default for files from this language group.